# Interface for diagrams and example

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I would like to know if there are interactive graphic-oriented programs to construct diagrams of latex.

For example, I know

https://q.uiver.app/

There are others that do something similar?

I am struggling to do this diagram on tikz:

[[image: diag]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true—TikZ can be intimidating at first. The 1000+ page manual is downright terrifying. But it's worth it! Start with some of the tutorials at the beginning of the manual. You'll be drawing pictures like these in no time!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{dot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=1pt},
    myarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position .6 with {\arrow{>}}}, postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle[radius=2];
\draw[very thick, myarrow] (-80:2)node[dot, label={-90:{$B'$}}]{}arc(-80:80:2)node[dot, label={90:{$A'$}}]{};
\draw[very thick, myarrow] (100:2)node[dot, label={90:{$A$}}]{}arc(100:260:2)node[dot, label={-90:{$B$}}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A small variation of the nice @Sandy G answer (+1) which gives wee bit shorter code. For exercise :-)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14159]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, label=#1},
->-/.style = {decoration={markings, 
                          mark=at position .52 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}
                          }, 
              very thick, 
              postaction={decorate}
              }
                    ]
\draw circle[radius=2];
\draw[->-]        (100:2)  node[dot=$A$ ] {}
            arc(100:260:2) node[dot=below:$B$ ] {};
\draw[->-]        (-80:2)  node[dot=below:$B'$] {} 
            arc(-80:80:2)  node[dot=$A'$] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Remarks*:

- on web are many services for, as they advertise, for simple drawing Ti*k*Z pictures, but as I see some results of such programs, the code mostly awful and full of clutter.
- The resulted code is easy to lost and when you stuck in drawing, is extremely hard to help you.
- One of interactive service is  [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/). Here on site are many answer which use it.
- I agree with @Sandy G, that the best way to draw Ti*k*Z images is learn Ti*k*Z. The best way is metod "learning-by doing". Any time, when you will stuck in programing of image, you can ask for help here.
- For start I suggest to read:

  - A very minimal introduction to TikZ, see [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en)
  - From package documentation read  2 Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students (page 31) and others tutorials, depends on what kind of images are in interest.
  - Basic about Ti*k*Z packed you can find in Part III: Ti*k*Z ist kein Zeichenprogramm
  - numerous examples are on site [TeXexamples.net](https://texample.net//) as well here on site
- At drawing is handy to use `standalone` package  as is done in above MWE (Minimal Working Example)

Happy TeXing!